# Django Multiple Form Usage

Tags: django, forms, post

How do I differentiate the post requests from different buttons in django? For instance, if I want to create a calculator, how do I make it so the POST of the "multiply" button is different from that of the "add" and the "subtract" buttons?
EDIT:

Here is my views.py:

```
     from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
     from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
     from django.template import RequestContext
     from django.views.generic import TemplateView
     from django import forms
     # Create your views here.

     # def startPage(request):
     #     return render(request, 'multiplication/detail.html')

    template_name1 = 'multiplication/detail.html'
    template_name2 = 'multiplication/multiplied.html'

    class myForm(forms.Form):
        quantity1 = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
        quantity2 = forms.IntegerField(required=False)

        def multiply_two_integers(x,y):
           return x*y

        def my_view(request):
           if request.method == 'POST':
              form = myForm(request.POST)
              if (form.is_valid()):
                x = form.cleaned_data['quantity1']
                y = form.cleaned_data['quantity2']
                product = multiply_two_integers(x, y)
                multiplied = True
               return render(request, template_name1, {'form': 
               form,'product': product, 'multiplied': multiplied })
               else:
               multiplied = False
              form = myForm()
              return render(request,template_name1,{'form': form, 
              'multiplied': multiplied} )
```

template_name1:

```
              <h1>Multiplication Function</h1>
              <form action =  "{% url 'multiplication:my_view' %}" 
              method = "POST">
              {{ form.as_p  }}
              {% csrf_token %}
              <input type = "submit" value ="Multiply">
              <input type = "submit" value ="Add">
              <!--<button type="submit"> Multiply </button>-->
              {% if multiplied %}
              <h1 style="color:blue; margin-left:75px;"> Answer: 
              {{product}}</h1>
              {% endif %}
              </form>
```

Comment: There are several approaches to achieve this. Can you include in your question what do you already have?

Comment: I added an edit